# How do i perform $in $regex array with case insensitivity?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How do i search a mongodb database via mongoose using a `$in` operator with `$regex` operating utilizing a array such as `["/servers/i", "/red hat/i"]`.

i am wanting to find something like

```
Report.find({scanMonth: {$in: result}, os: {$in: REGEX ARRAY},'ip scanMonth os crit', function(err, results)
```

my problem is the `<Array>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine those conditions with `$and` and `$or` like:

```
Report.find({ $and: [ { scanMonth: {$in: result} }, { $or: [ { os: { "$regex": "/servers/i" } }, { os: { "$regex": "/red hat/i" } }  ] } ],'ip scanMonth os crit', function(err, results)
```